# Why would ld sha1sum differ on two different machines?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc, g++, ld

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed on two machines, both 64 bits. On one PC 14.04.1 and on the other one 14.04.3.

Both have the same version of gcc, g++ and ld:
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.24
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4

The sha1sum of gcc and g++ is the same on both machines but the sha1sum of ld differs if I have the same version on the machines.

Machine 1:

```
sha1sum /usr/bin/ld.bfd
5a5e853772ef1077ba7be58bba83a6c899993ce8  /usr/bin/ld.bfd
```

Machine 2:

```
sha1sum /usr/bin/ld.bfd
7bc36121f6975db169d350cab317bab075fd82e5  /usr/bin/ld.bfd
```

I've checked that /usr/bin/ld points to /usr/bin/ld.bfd on both machines.

If I compile the same source code on both machines I get different behavior ... is this possible because of different ld ? 
Is there any library that, once installed on a ubuntu machine, could modify the ld binary ?

**EDIT:**

```
ld.bfd -v
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.24
```

Comment: What does `ld.bfd -v` produce on both machines?

Comment: "If I compile the same source code on both machines I get different behavior... is this possible because of different ld?" a more possible reason would be the code itself

Comment: I added the output of ld.bfd -v to the mai post. The different behavior is because of opencv 3.0 that I compile on both machines with the same flags. On one machine, highgui library of opencv spawns a thread that does poll() for images from a web cam and on the other machine this thread does not appear .

Comment: That difference probably comes from some difference in the libraries or the hardware.

Comment: Do you know what libraries may affect the ld binary ?

Comment: What does `dpkg -l binutils` give as version on both machines? (binutils is the package containing `ld`)